# Setting Dialog ImageView from Activity

Tags: android, imageview, android-alertdialog, photo, onactivityresult

Android beginner here..

I have a method in my Dialog Fragment to take a photo:

```
public void takePhoto() {
    Intent takePhoto = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    getActivity().startActivityForResult(takePhoto, REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO);
}
```

And I realize that the onActivityResult method has to be in the "fragment calling activity", but how would I set an ImageView in the Dialog from the onActivityResult?

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
        Bitmap imageBitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
        // Set an ImageView in my Dialog Fragment
        mImageView.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap);
    }
}
```

**SOLUTION:**

Declared this field in my DialogFragment:

```
private static View layout; 

...

layout = View.inflate(mContext, R.layout.new_post_dialog_layout, null);
```

Added this method to my DialogFragment:

```
public static ImageView getDialogImageView() {
    ImageView iv = (ImageView) layout.findViewById(R.id.imagePost);
    return iv;
}
```

Modified the onActivityResult:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
        Bitmap imageBitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
        NewPostDialog.getDialogImageView().setImageBitmap(imageBitmap);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would think you could just create a public method in your dialog that gives access to the image view in its custom view.

So like `public ImageView getDialogImageView()`, then in your activity just check if the Image view is null and if not then set the image in `onActivityResult`. You might also want to use a WeakReference to do this so it can be garbage collected when you're done.

Comment: what's an easy way to get the image view in the getDialogImageView() method?

Comment: Make the image view a field of your dialog and then return that image view in the method i posted above.

Comment: OK it worked. I had to make the method and the layout used to find the image view static. Solution is shown in question.

Comment: You dont have to make it static if you have a reference to your dialog fragment in your activity but im glad it worked!